# Parsing through a CSV file

Tags: shell

I have a CSV files like this:

```
2015-12-10,22:45:00,205,5626,85
2015-12-10,23:00:01,79,5625,85
2015-12-13,13:00:01,4410,5629,85
2015-12-13,13:15:00,4244,5627,85
2015-12-13,13:30:00,4082,5627,85
```

I tried this script to generate an SQL statement:

```
#!/bin/bash

inputfile=${1}
echo $inputfile
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
while read date time current full cycle
do
echo -—$date --$time --$current --$full --$cycle
echo insert into table values($date,$time,$current,$full,$cycle)
sleep 1
done < $inputfile
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

But on execution I get this error and it doesn't run as expected:

```
/Scripts/CreateSql.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Scripts/CreateSql.sh: line 10: `echo insert into table values(\$date,$time,$current,$full,$cycle)'
```

I need the statement generated like this:

```
insert into table values($date,$time,$current,$full,$cycle)
```

Please kindly suggest a fix for this.

Answer (score 2):

Use double quotes as anything under `()` to shell means spawn a new process.

```
echo "insert into table values($date,$time,$current,$full,$cycle)"
```

Comment: Sma, still the same-
`/Scripts/CreateSql.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Scripts/CreateSql.sh: line 10: `echo “insert into table values($date,$time,$current,$full,$cycle)”'`

Comment: @AlanJebakumar The answer is correct. Try Remove the "smart" substitutions in your terminal app. Seems it replaces the ascii `"` with the unicode `“`.

Comment: @jm666: Im not sure how to proceed on what you suggested. Can you advise me on how to remove the `"smart"` substitutions?

Comment: @AlanJebakumar i havent idea what is your environment. I only saw your comment, where is clearly used the: `“` and it IS different from the wanted `"`.

Comment: @jm666: I was able to get this fixed by-
`echo 'insert into elangovan21_alanj_test.BatteryInfo values ('"'$date'"','"'$time'"','$current','$full','$cycle');'`

Answer (score 0):

All,

i fixed this-

```
 echo 'insert into table values ('$date','$time','$current','$full','$cycle')'
```